# Windows GDI: taking a screenshot as DIB results in ALL BLACK

Tags: winapi, bitmap, screenshot, gdi, bitmapimage

I'm pretty new to Windows API/GDI. All I want to do in this piece of code is to take a FULL-screenshot into my memory buffer.

```
int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    int width = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
    int height = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );
    char *bmpBuf;
    FILE* bmpFile;
    HDC dcScreen = GetDC( NULL );
    HDC dcCapt = CreateCompatibleDC( dcScreen );
    HBITMAP hbmpCapt = CreateCompatibleBitmap( dcScreen, width, height );
    BITMAP bmpCapt;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    size_t bmpSize;
    SelectObject( dcCapt, hbmpCapt );
    BitBlt( dcCapt, 0,0, width, height, dcScreen, 0,0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT );
    GetObject( hbmpCapt, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpCapt );
    bmpSize = ((bmpCapt.bmWidth*32+31)/32)*4*bmpCapt.bmHeight;
    bmpBuf = (char*)malloc( bmpSize );
    GetDIBits( dcCapt, hbmpCapt, 0, (UINT)bmpCapt.bmHeight, bmpBuf, (LPBITMAPINFO)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS );

    bmpFile = fopen( "screenshot.raw", "w" );
    if( !bmpFile )
        printf( "Can't open file\n" );
    else {
        fwrite( bmpBuf, 1, bmpSize, bmpFile );
        fclose( bmpFile );
    }
    printf( "Image( %d x %d ) written\n", bmpCapt.bmWidth, bmpCapt.bmHeight );

    DeleteDC( dcCapt );
    DeleteObject( hbmpCapt );

    return 0;
}
```

I managed to save my memory buffer into a .raw file. However, when I open this .raw file in Photoshop(I tell PS its size and format), I see ALL BLACK. So there must be something wrong in my code. I just can't find the bug!

Comment: There's no error checking in this code at all.  So of course you don't know why it failed.  Don't ignore the return value of winapi functions.

Comment: In addition to Hans' point, have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: I finally found that I opened the file in CYMK mode! If I write the complete file with BMP header&infoheader, the code works! Oh man, that's foolish. Anyway, thank to all the geeks trying to help me out!